# Firebase: Como carregar dados randômicos em um RecyclerView?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, random, firebase

Estou usando uma Query para carregar apenas 6 itens do Firebase database no RecyclerView mas até o momento só consigo ordenar utilizando o orderByChild, limitToFirst or last. Tudo está funcionando bem mas...

Quero carregar itens de maneira randômica no RecyclerView quando a activity for carregada.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? O Firebase, infelizmente, não tem uma Query Randômica, todas seguem ordens definidas.

Meu código:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Category");
query = mDatabase.limitToFirst(6); 

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(final CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
    viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImagem());
    viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        });
    }
};

mImagesList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

Meu adapter:

```
public static class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setImage(Context ctx, String image1) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image1).into(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode fazer uma query para buscar, por exemplo, vinte imagens diferentes e depois no Android embaralha via Java e exibe apenas 10 delas. Já que é só txt, então não gasta muito a internet.

Comment: A ideia do Mr_Anderson não é recomendada porque você estará forçando o usuário a utilizar mais internet do que ele realmente precisa.

Comment: Você pode criar uma função em javascript que gere números randômicos e colocar como uma função do Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo que você adicione mais uma variável para a sua classe modelo. Algo como um "id". E guarde valores aleatórios nele (De 0 à 15 por exemplo). Aí você cria um método que gera valores aleatórios (vamos chamar esse método de `gerarAleatorio()`). Assim, quando voce quiser dados aleatórios, você pode usar a query assim:

```
query = mDatabase.orderByChild("id").startAt(gerarAleatorio()).limitToFirst(6);
```